# Accurate Translations of Yen's Cantonese dialogue from Ocean's Eleven?

Tags: dialogue, oceans-eleven

I've always been curious what Yen is saying when he speaks Cantonese in the movie Ocean's Eleven.

I'm going to post some rough translations I managed to get from Google Translate, but I'm sure they're a little off. I'd love for a fluent Cantonese speaker to help get them right.

Comment: in the planning meeting at Reuben's house, Google Translate gave me "Why not dig a hole under the ground"?

Comment: interestingly - none of Yen's non-English lines seem to be written in the script: http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/oceans_11.pdf - just the reactions from Rusty as translator.

Comment: can you post links to which clips you want translated?

Comment: I'll see if I can find links... but there may be only 2: the planning session in Reuben's house, and in the van when Linus is missing/in trouble.

Comment: actually, Yen isn't speaking Cantonese, it's Mandarin. If you think about it, Cantonese has a more stern, 'angry' tone but Mandarin could be said to be more 'relaxed'. Plus his accent when he speaks English when Russ and Danny break through into the vault is definitely not a Cantonese accent, so he should be speaking Mandarin.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. In the planning meeting at Reuben's house, he said "我们为何不从地下挖个洞 钻过去"
   The google translate it correctly as  "Why not dig a hole under the ground" to enter the vault in Mandarin.
2. In the van when Linus missing, it should be "不听我们的 他一定死定了" . It can translate to "he didn't listen to us, he's definitely in big trouble now" in Mandarin